# preg_match numbers negative and positive

Tags: regex, preg-match

I need to fix this `preg_match("/^[[0-9]{0,4}$/i", $input)`, it also need accept negative values. Thanks

Comment: Just out of interest, did you _mean_ to have two `[` characters at the start, or is that a typo? You may also want to fix the lower bound from 0 to 1 since `""` is not really a number, and `-` definitely isn't :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/^-?[0-9]{1,4}$/', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: +1 though I'd set the lower bound to 1 since a number should have at least _one_ digit.

Answer (score 0):

Like everything else in PHP, there's a dedicated function.

Check out [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Comment: Really? What does PHP have as a dedicated function for calculating `e` to the power of `pi` to the power of `n` minus Avagadro's constant? `etopitonlessava(n)` ? :-)